# Timetable schedule in Excel

Tags: excel, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, solver

I try to make a simple timetable / schedule for some subject taught in school using the solver in Excel.

This is the setup:

[image]

Whereas the Cost, Timetable/Schedule, Demand and Supply matrix are hardcoded. The "Math Assigned" is the sum og respectively the column and row, and the objective is to minimize the "total cost", which is defined as the sumproduct between the Cost matrix and the Timetable/Schedule matrix.

Using the Solver in Excel I'm only able to Assign one subject in this case Math.

Here is what I wrote in the solver:

[image]

Which result in the Math classes being allocated:

[image]

**Question**

How can I best allocate the other subjects aswell?

**EDIT**

I tried adding a Timetable/Schedule for the subject English (Now there is one for Math and for English).
Now the total cost is to minimize the sumproduct of Math timetable and Cost matrix + sumproduct of English timetable and the same Cost matrix.
And additionally added constraints for English corresponding to the constraint for Math.

How can I avoid (maybe using a constraint) the solver from placing ones in the same entries in the binary matrices (Math Timetable and English Timetable), when the use the same cost matrix?

An example, where two matrices share a 1 in the same entry:

[image]

**Solution**

I solved it myself, by adding a helper matrix which sums each of the entries and defining that matrix to be less than a matrix only containing ones.

However, If someone can come up with a less extensive solution, I will approve the solution. Since this is just a minimal example and I will absolutely love to make it more simple and efficient.

Comment: if this is a minimal solution then it is already simple and efficient.

Comment: My solution contains a matrix for each subject and it may also be necessary with a cost matrix for each subject if it's not the same teacher in all subjects. In the resulting solution there may be a a lot of matrices. It would be convenient to avoid all these matrices, somehow. In the case of 1 subject there would be 4 matrices and 2 vectors. 2 subjects would be 7 matrices and 4 vectors (due to the helper matrices). 3 subjects would be 8 matrices and 6 vectors. And so on (theses numbers are assuming the subjects shares the cost matrix).